# Image Transform in template 'Auto' errors

Tags: image-transforms

The docs state:

> format can be set to 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', or 'Auto'.

*Why is it 'Auto' not 'auto'?!

https://craftcms.com/docs/image-transforms#possible-values

I'm using a variable to define the transform settings:

```
{% set small = {
    mode:       'fit',
    width:      800,
    height:     600,
    quality:    80,
    position:   'center-center',
    format:     'Auto'
} %}
```

But Craft errors with:

> Imagine\Exception\InvalidArgumentException Saving image in "auto"
>   format is not supported, please use one of the following extensions:
>   "gif", "jpeg", "png", "wbmp", "xbm"

Is this a bug or is my code incorrect?

Comment: Does this work without the 'format' parameter?
Are you using ImageMagik or GD?

Comment: Yes it works without, so I'm assuming it defaults to Auto. Must be GD as I've not installed ImageMagik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an error in the docs. You get the automatic format assignment by default, no need to explicitly set `format: 'auto'`.